# How to cast to dynamic type at generic function?

Tags: generics, casting, haxe

I have a basic prototype class:

```
class CItemProto {

    public var id:Int;

    public var count:Int;

    ...
}
```

and some extensions of different kind:

```
class CItemThing extends CItemProto { ... }
class CItemResource extends CItemProto { ... }
class CItemRecipe extends CItemProto { ... }
```

...and so on. Every instance of item has unique id, so I can store all my stuff in one inventory class with simple IntMap access:

```
class CInventory {

    var mMap:IntMap<CItemProto>;

    public function new() {
        mMap = new IntMap();
    }

    public inline function set(item:CItemProto) { mMap.set(item.id, item); }

    public function get<T:CItemProto>(id:Int):T {
        var item = mMap.get(aId);
        if (Std.is(item, Class<T>)) // it doesn't work saying Unexpected )
            return cast item;
        return null;
    }

}
```

My point is to use **get()** accessor with some item id and this item type and if I wrong in type selection, method should return **null** value. For example:

```
// should return instance of CItemThing if it exists or null in the other way
var thing:CItemThing = inventory.get(123);
```

But it doesn't work. Simple unsafe cast fails if I request wrong type, safe cast demands **Dynamic** type instead of generic **T** substitution. What should I do in order to filter requested items by their type? Of cause I can pass type as second argument but it looks bulky and excessive.

**UPDATE** I have found topic [How to look for a class type in an array using generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588011/how-to-look-for-a-class-type-in-an-array-using-generics) so my question have no sense. I'll pass desired type as second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
public function safeGetAs<T:CItemProto>(id:Int, c:Class<T>):T {
    var v = mMap.get(id);
    if (Std.is(v, c)) return cast v;
    return null;
}
```

Then you have to explicit type what you want, because this is not something that can be resolved compiletime. The typing also then makes more sense:

```
inventory.set(new CItemThing(1));
inventory.set(new CItemResource(2));

var a = inventory.safeGetAs(1, CItemThing);
trace(a); // returns instance
$type(a); // expected: CItemThing. is: CItemThing. 

var b = inventory.safeGetAs(2, CItemThing);
trace(b); // returns null
$type(b); // expected: CItemThing. is: CItemResource.
```

Demo: http://try.haxe.org/#65792

Comment: Thanks, I've made the same solution. Now I see that it isn't drawback to pass a class as type of expected data.

Comment: You can use `return Std.instance(v, c)` to replace the `if..return cast...return null`

Answer (score -1):

I've made one really ugly workaround:

```
typedef Constructible = {
    function new():Void;
}

@:generic
public function get<T:(CItemProto,Constructible)>(id:Int):Null<T> {
    var typed = new T();
    var item:CItemProto = mMap.get(id);
    if (Std.is(item, Type.getClass(typed)))
        return cast item;
    return null;
}
```

And now I can request an item of any type like:

```
var thing:CItemThing = inventory.get(111);
var resource:CItemResource = inventory.get(222);
```

But you shouldn't do like this.

Comment: Creating an instance to get it's class? Why even posting an answer that ends up with 'But you shouldn't do like this.'.